# How can I make my event work on all datatable pages?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, onclick

When click on `.mytext` after my datatable is loaded, then I get an alert. But this is only working on the first page of the datatable pagination. If I go to another page it is not working anymore.

```
   var table = $('#table').DataTable({
     "ajax": {
            "url": "data/table.json",
            "dataSrc": "",
        },

      "columns": [
            {
                "data": "id"
            },
            {
                "data": "name"
            },
            {
                "data": "age"
            }
        ],
       initComplete: function () {
          $(".mytext").on("click", function () {
             alert("something happens");
          });
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use event `delegation` (http://api.jquery.com/on/). Instead of binding directly on the element, you bind on `document` or a "parent element" and you set the `target`.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".mytext", function () {
    alert("something happens");
});
```